# Why skews a element with a Y set move it also across X?

Tags: svg, skew

Here's [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1p6kL3fd/5/) with X/Y set to 0:

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;" />

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;"
        transform="skewX(50)" />
</svg>
```

Which is correct.

Why if I [set](https://jsfiddle.net/1p6kL3fd/6/) an Y value to the skew element it also move on the X-axis?

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;" />

  <rect x="0" y="10" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;"
        transform="skewX(50)" />
</svg>
```

I would expect an offset only on the Y-axis, not also on the X-axis. In fact if I apply only to X, it just offset in the X-axis, not Y.

Answer (score 0):

A transformation `skewX(angle)` is computed as follows:

```
x' = x + y * tan(angle)
y' = y
```

So if the upper left corner of your rectangle is at `(0, 10)`, with `skewX(50)` it will be mapped to `(11.92, 10)`.

In other words, the center of transformation is always at coordinates `(0, 0)`.